# How to get attending guests count from event using FB Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I would like to get attending guests count from event using [Facebook Graph API v2.1](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer). I can't use FQL Query becouse it is deprecated after current version.

I can use **/{event-id}/attending** and sum all guests but this solution is very ineffective (queries are performed for a long time - usually >2000ms and it work only for ~1000 guests, not more).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you make a call to the Event ID itself, you can add fields for `attending_count`, `declined_count` and `maybe_count` to get the totals easily.

Example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{event_id}?fields=attending_count,declined_count,maybe_count
```

If I do the following:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/468185256651918?fields=attending_count,declined_count,maybe_count
```

I see:

```
{
  "attending_count": 304, 
  "declined_count": 277, 
  "maybe_count": 97, 
  "start_time": "2014-09-06T20:00:00+0100", 
  "id": "468185256651918"
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! One more question: How you know that? I read the API documentation but I haven't found that information.

Comment: I found the fields on the following reference page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/event/